# Apache OFBiz integration with Cassandra and Eventual Consistency

Tags: cassandra, ofbiz, eventual-consistency

Apache OFBiz supposedly integrates with Apache Cassandra databases. But does it support the eventual consistency feature? 
If yes can anyone point me in the direction of some documentation or some written content explaining how?
If no - does OFBiz integrate and support any other database with eventual consistency?

Thanks in advance,
Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the integration of OFBiz with a Cassandra database has been mentioned in a couple of occasions in the OFBiz mailing lists, I am not aware of any setup of OFBiz that can work properly without a relational database.

Even if there are JDBC drivers for Cassandra, I doubt Cassandra can provide all the relational database features required by OFBiz.

The integration of OFBiz with Cassandra or any other big data tool is achievable and it is done by pairing the relational database with another ad-hoc database for specific purposes.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any effort to implement OFBiz on a database that supports the Eventual consistency model.